# Android hexadecimal to decimal conversion

Tags: java, android, obd-ii

I need some help in converting the answers I get from my OBD adapter in my car to decimal and then later adding whatever value comes out of the conversion to a formula and printed out.

```
public void run() {
     OBDcmds();

     try {
         OdbRawCommand ANS = new OdbRawCommand("22 40 90");


         while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
             Log.d("Log", "ANS: " + ANS.getFormattedResult());

             try {
                 ANS.run(mmInStream, mmOutStream);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("inside catch before while");
            }
        }
```

ANS when asked will return something like "6240901F30" where the first 6 numbers are irrelevant to the answer (<s>624090</s>1F30). So what we have left is the last (in this case) 4 numbers (1F30) which are in Hexadecimal and need to be converted to Decimal. This value is then later added to a formula `x * 0,0625 - 512`. It needs to jump over those six first numbers otherwise the answer will be wrong.

How would I be able to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.parseInt` with the "radix" argument :

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("1F30", 16));
```

**Output :**

> 7984

Comment: @EvgeniyMishustin also known as "base", it is the number of different digits that exist in a given numerical representation. For example, `binary <=> radix = 2`; `octal <=> radix = 8`; `hexadecimal <=> radix = 16`.

Comment: Altough "1F30" in not a static value. Meaning that "1F30" will update to a different number since I have it in a while-loop. This is calculating the current of the battery in the car, therefore this will not work sadly.

Comment: @swess You can replace the constant with any String variable.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, ah thanx, just always used the "base" word! Every day learn somthing new!

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Ah ok, how?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle http://stackoverflow.com/q/37249947/5908129