# How do I edit a github Android API?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, github-api

Is it possible to edit a [API](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) that i'm using in Android Studio?

I can't edit this because it seems like it's locked.

[image]

The reason I want to edit this is because of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37249947/5908129).

Comment: Open it in notepad(or any other editor)?

Comment: it's a jar file tough

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure how it works with jars nowadays, but with old jar games for mobiles I did it like this: duplicate jar twice, unzip one jar, edit file, copy&paste to second jar file through 7zip and it worked. Backup the original.